# Exchange 2016 management tool install on Windows 10

Tags: exchange-2016

I tried to install Exchange 2016 management tool on my laptop running Windows 10 pro 64 bit. So, I enabled necessary IIS feature for that. Then I ran setup and I got follow error message on readiness check state.

[image: Readiness checks error]

Comment: Your laptop is domain joined ?

Comment: Yes joined but i'm now using my home internet access and doesn't have vpn route to our DC.

Comment: Your error is there, it try to talk to your DC

Comment: Oh.. ok I will try to connect vpn first. then try again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the tool while you are in your office and please set your VPN to be able to talk to your DC/Exchange if you intend to use the toolkit.